# In a MVC pattern, is it ok for a controller to create it own view?

Tags: java, design-patterns, model-view-controller, view, controller

I know that the `view` isn't supposed to know it's `controller`, but is it ok for a `controller` to create its own `view` or should the `view` always be passed as a parameter to the `controller`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With out context is not easy to to answer, but generally speaking no. The controller, view and model should be defined at the interface level (or at least highly abstract) so a controller can be made to control multiple different views which implement the required contract.

Having said that, a controller might be required to create new views, for example in a wizard style setup, but in this case, I would either use a model or factory approach to perform the physical operation, making the controller further flexible

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. If i can ask, a controller should control multiple views? or should they have each a different controller?

Comment: No, a controller and a view is generally a one to one relationship

Comment: It should be noted, that over its lifetime, a controller could be responsible for controlling more then one view, but it would only control one view at a time

Comment: You are making me question myself about its utility now. When should i use a MVC pattern?

Comment: MVC should be used when ever possible, to separate the functionality of the view from the implementation details and keep the data that the view is responsible for visualising separate. All I'm saying is that there is, typically, a one to one relationship between an instance of a view and an instance of a controller, but over the lifetime of the application, either one might change (ie the same instance of a controller might be used to mange multiple views, but it will only ever manage one at a time)